# I am not able to Delete an item from a list in Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have some lists of stations in my template when I tried deleting directly without using the confirmation modal interface it worked perfectly but when I tried using the confirmation modal, it only deleted the id of the last item in my database. How can I fix this, please?

Note: Every time I click the delete button on any of the list items, every one of the show `localhost:8000/deletestation/5` but I want it to delete only the specific station.

views.py

```
@login_required
def DeleteStation(request, pk):

    station = Station.objects.get(id=pk)
    station.delete()

    context = {"station":station}

    return render(request, "core/stations.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('deletestation/<str:pk>/', DeleteStation, name="deletestation"),
]
```

stations.html

```
<tbody>
    {% for station in stations %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
        <td>{{station.name}}</td>
        <td>{{station.description}}</td>
        <td>{{station.macaddress}}</td>
        <td>{{station.address}}</td>
        <td>{{station.ipaddress}}</td>
        <td>{{station.status}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'editstation' station.pk %}"><i style="font-size: 22px;" class="fa fa-search"></i></a></td>
        <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_station" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <i style="font-size: 22px;" class="dw dw-delete-3"></i>

    <div class="modal fade" id="delete_station" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirm Deletion</h5>
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO DELETE THIS STATION</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'deletestation' station.pk %}">Proceed</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: are you using javascript involved?

Comment: No javascript is involved

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you load the core/stations.html with the DeleteStation view, the "station" context is the just-deleted Station obj. Based on the code showing, I'm not clear how you're able to get a list of stations to show up at all, (maybe you cut it out for clarity).

I'd recommend making a separate view for the list, and just have the DeleteStation view redirect to the list view:

views.py

```
@login_required
def DeleteStation(request, pk):

    station = get_object_or_404(Station, id=pk)
    station.delete()

    return redirect(reverse("station:list"))

@login_required
def StationList(request, pk):

    stations = Station.objects.all()
    context = {"stations":station}

    return render(request, "core/stations.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('deletestation/<str:pk>/', DeleteStation, name="deletestation"),
    path('stations/', StationList, name="stations"),
]
```